# Copy sums from one Excel file to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have one file (Book 1) with a column of numbers and a formula to sum them up. I need to copy that sum from Book 1 to a cell in Book 2, Book 3, etc. I end up copying the formula and moving it, not the sum itself.

```
Sub CopyInfo()
    experiment1.Range("F7").Value = experiment2.Range("I5").Value
    experiment1.Range("F7").Copy
    experiment2.Range("I5").Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I'm trying to copy from "experiment1" to "experiment2".

Comment: can you post your actual code ?

Comment: @Jilian: this code seems to copy the value from expt2:I5 and then just paste it back again. Is that intended?  In general you shouldn't copy/paste unless you need to: here you can assign values directly **expt1.Range("I5").Value = expt2.Range("F7").Value**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Paste, use PasteSpecial like this:

```
experiment2.Range("I5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This will paste the calculated value instead of the formula.

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew it was something trivial I was missing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a past special, so you would have:

```
dim wkb1 as workbook, wkb2 as workbook
Dim r1 as range, r2 as range

set wkb1=workbooks("wkb1")
set wkb2=workbooks("wkb2")
set r1=wkb1.worksheets("whatever").range("A1")
set r2=wkb2.worksheets("whatever2").range("A1")
r1.copy
r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Make sure you give +1s to the answers you like and mark as answered the person that you feel best answered your question. We like our points :)

Comment: Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to vote things up yet. I did mark it as helpful though. :)